# python inotify to monitor for In_closted_write and in_moved_to events

Tags: python, inotify

I am monitoring a directory for new files to be moved to or created.
Upon detecting the new file I call a another python script to process the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import signal
import sys
import logging
import inotify.adapters
import subprocess

_DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT = ''

_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def _configure_logging():
    _LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()

    formatter = logging.Formatter(_DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    _LOGGER.addHandler(ch)

def exit_gracefully(signum, frame):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_sigint)
    sys.exit(1)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_gracefully)

def main():
    i = inotify.adapters.Inotify()

    i.add_watch(b'/home/sort/tmp')

    try:
        for event in i.event_gen():
            if event is not None:
                if 'IN_MOVED_TO' in event[1] or 'IN_CLOSE_WRITE' in event[1]:
                    (header, type_names, watch_path, filename) = event
                    _LOGGER.info("%s" #"WD=(%d) MASK=(%d) COOKIE=(%d) LEN=(%d) MASK->NAMES=%s "
                         #"WATCH-PATH=[%s]"
                         "FILENAME=%s" + "/" + "%s",
                         type_names,#header.wd, header.mask, header.cookie, header.len, type_names,
                         watch_path.decode('utf-8'), filename.decode('utf-8'))
                fnp = str(event[2] + "/" + event[3])
                print fnp
                proc = subprocess.Popen([orgpath, fnp], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=1)
                #proc.communicate()
    finally:
        i.remove_watch(b'/home/sort/tmp')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _configure_logging()

    orgdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
    orgpath = os.path.join(orgdir, "organize.py")

    original_sigint = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_gracefully)
    print("Watching /home/sort/tmp for new files")
    main()
```

The end goal is to only process one file at a time as I call to an API to scrape for metadata. To many calls to the API in a short period of time could result in the API key to be banned or temporarily blocked.

Right now when I copy more than a single file into the monitoring directory the script gets called on each file at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a for loop to run the python file..

```
for files in directory:
    ...code that runs the python file
```

if it is still running too fast, you can put a timer on to throttle the API calls

```
import time
for files in directory:
    ...code that runs the python file
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Would the for loop go around orgpath or subprocess?

Comment: probably proc/subprocess but i cannot be too sure.. maybe its the main() function.. im not 100% sure how it works and i cannot replicate it because i dont know what the organise.py does lol..

Comment: oraganize.py isn't completed yet, but in its current form.

Comment: It processes the archive to get into to make an api. write the result to json. Make 2 additional api calls to get more info, which is also written to json. The results of the api calls with eventually get written to a sqlite db. The file will then be moved to a folder that is created based on the results obtained from the api calls. If the file can't be identified via API it will get moved to another folder for manual processing.